# Simple positioning problem for child element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I have this for loop to create HTML.

```js
let content;
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    content = "Stack Overflow is a question and answer website for professional and enthusiast programmers. It is the flagship site of the Stack Exchange Network,[4][5][6] created in 2008 by Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky.[7][8]"
  } else {
    content = "Stack Overflow is a question and answer website for professional and enthusiast programmers."
  }
  document.body.innerHTML += `
<div class='whole'>
<p>${content}</p>
<button class='buttons'>Click</button>
<button class='buttons'>ADD</button>
</div>`
}
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 50px;
  grid-row-gap: 50px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
}
.whole {
  width: 200px;
}
.buttons {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 200px
}
```

This all works fine, but I want to let the button position always keep the same position (vertcially) with the other buttons.

Now in my code, the button's height will be affected by the length and other child elements (`p`). I try use `position:absolute` or `position:sticky`, but both of them doesn't solve my problem.

Is there a way to make the position of child element to be absolute to only child element?

The effect I want to achieve are all the buttons could always have same vertically position with others.

[image]

Comment: What if the text in one panel was longer than the page length? Why should I have to scroll down in another panel that had just a few lines just to be able to click a button? This doesn't sound like a good UX decision.

Comment: @Andy, I agree with that, but actually I have more code and my attempt doesn't really look the same with my example above, since Stackoverflow ask us to create minimal example, I create a rough design:)

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to achieve is the buttons to be vertically aligned on the same line, you can simply use CSS flexbox in `.whole`. By forcing the flex direction to `column` and then forcing spaces to be inserted between its children via `justify-content: space-between`, you can pretty much achieve what you want:

```js
let content;
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    content = "Stack Overflow is a question and answer website for professional and enthusiast programmers. It is the flagship site of the Stack Exchange Network,[4][5][6] created in 2008 by Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky.[7][8]"
  } else {
    content = "Stack Overflow is a question and answer website for professional and enthusiast programmers."
  }
  document.body.innerHTML += `
<div class='whole'>
<p>${content}</p>
<button class='buttons'>Click</button>
</div>`
}
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 50px;
  grid-row-gap: 50px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
}

.whole {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.buttons {
  position: relative;
  width: min-content;
  left: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Nice use of CSS Grid.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just wonder what if I have two buttons, I know this is my problem of doesn't showing that before in my code, but I create two buttons in every loop and this ways seems not working, is there a way I could deal with that?

Comment: @jason Depends on how you want to position them. It’s not clear how you want to, but a solution is to wrap the buttons in a div element.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution using a grid. Make whole a grid item and then use place-self and grid-row-start to place the buttons at the end; You can learn the complete working of grid [here at CSS tricks.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

```js
let content;
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    content = "Stack Overflow is a question and answer website for professional and enthusiast programmers. It is the flagship site of the Stack Exchange Network,[4][5][6] created in 2008 by Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky.[7][8] Stack Overflow is a question and answer website for professional and enthusiast programmers."
  } else {
    content = "Stack Overflow is a question and answer website for professional and enthusiast programmers."
  }
  document.body.innerHTML += `
<div class='whole'>
<p>${content}</p>
<button class='buttons'>Click</button>
<button class='buttons'>ADD</button>
</div>`
}
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 50px;
  grid-row-gap: 50px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
}
.whole {
  display: grid;
  width: 200px;
  column-gap: 5px;
}
.buttons {
  position: relative;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  height: 20px;
  place-self: end;
}
```